# Parse Push notification not sending from Android to Channel

Tags: android, parsing, notifications, push

I'm using Parse, When I send a push notification from the website to my phone (Specific Channel), it works fine. But when I try to send a notification FROM my phone to the same channel ( or everyone ) it doesn't send.

I'm sending it with an onClick of a button.

(Code is very very long so I'll crop out the relevant pieces)

(This is oncreate btw)

```
Parse.initialize(this, "CODE", "CODE");

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Channel1");
    //PushService.startServiceIfRequired(this);
```

-

```
case R.id.sendButton:


        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        String message = "Test" ; 
        //push.setChannel("Channel1");
        push.setMessage(message);
        push.sendInBackground();


        break;
```

(Yes, the button does work)

Anyone able to help me? What am I doing wrong?

Can provide more info if desired!

Yes, I have read the documentation of Parse. I Just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I've also trying ParsePush.send(); , Ignoring threads. Not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([Question answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer to match the Q&A format of StackOverflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))

The OP wrote:

> Alright, so after some more research, I've found this :
>
> [image]
>
> in the push settings on the website. This basically enables sending from clients (devices) to other people.
>
> **And also, a dumb mistake, forgetting to put .setOnClickListener on my button..**